# Changing Radius of Google Places Search Removes Some Results

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using a url similar to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.5136,-0.1365&radius=5000&keyword=coral to search for these shops within an area.

However, if I change the radius from 5000 to 20000 I will often not find some of the results that appear in the radius=5000 search, although they should be included in the area.

Why am I dropping results at a larger area?

Comment: try and see what is the limit for your result is

Comment: You should understand that Places API doesn't work as a database search. Not all possible results are returned. When you increase the radius another more prominent places can appear and the less prominent from previous search can disappear. You can have only 60 results in total (20 per page) in the response.

Comment: @MohammedAlSafwan I believe this was my problem. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Sixtoo good to hear :) mark it as an answer when you have the time, so others can get the same help ^.^